# How to add a external javascript file postman environment?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

How to add an external javascript file postman environment? I want to use some external javascript for Pre-request Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your JS code into an (environment) variable.

Then use `eval()` to execute that code.

It's explained here in detail: https://blog.postman.com/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/#tip-5-reuse-code